# How do I ssh into a machine, wait for a prompt, and then send a bunch of commands to it?

Tags: linux, expect

How do I do the following?

1. SSH to a `machine`, probably using expect since this is a script and I can't type the password for it
2. Wait for a prompt from the machine.  The prompt is `->`
3. Then send a bunch of commands from the original host to the machine I ssh'd to.  *Note that the output from these commands can contain the characters `->`*
4. Exit

Here are the contents of `some-commands.txt`:

```
first command
second command
third command
```

Here are the contents of the expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set f [open "some-commands.txt"]
set cmds [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no root@machine

interact -o -nobuffer -re "Password:" return
send "password\r"
# look for the prompt
set prompt "\n-> "

foreach cmd $cmds {
    send "$cmd\r";
    # The following works, except for the commands
    # whose output include ->
    interact -o -nobuffer -re "-> " return
}
```

The problem is that the interact command captures the `->` from the command output instead of the prompt, which hasn't yet arrived at that point.

Comment: Is that the whole prompt? Could you anchor the re match to be the whole line?

Comment: You don't need to `eval spawn ...` -- just `spawn ...`

Comment: That is indeed the whole prompt.  I think one change I can make is having interact match with `-exact "\n-> "`.  At least then, the `->` would have to occur on a new line to match.  Does that seem right?  Unfortunately, I can't test it at the moment.  I'll follow-up on Monday.  Also, I've gotten rid of eval.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to accomplish the same thing by doing something like:

`ssh -t -t -C user@host 'bash -s' < my_shell_script.sh param1 paramX`

Where `my_shell_script.sh` is an simple shell script.

The trick here is use multiple `-t` to force pseudo-terminal over `ssh` and the `-s` option to `bash` witch makes it reads the commands from the standard input.

Comment: Ah, I've clarified my question.  I think the reason this idea won't work is that I can't pass in the password with the ssh call.  In this particular case, SSH keys aren't an option, and neither is sshpass.  Sorry about not stating that originally.